# Why I get compile error in IntelliJ IDEA 11?

Tags: 11.10, ide

I recently switched to Ubuntu 11.10. I checked out my project from svn and created the required modules and libraries in IntelliJ as always. But for some reason I can't compile the project and I get:

```
Error: *.class (No such file or directory)
```

for all of the classes in the project. I checked the project structure and everything seems normal. I can't even guess what the problem might be. The only difference in the project under Ubuntu from Windows is that I used Sun Java 6 in Windows but now I'm using OpenJDK 6. 
I will provide more details if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a IntelliJ user, but I do use PyCharm everyday. JetBrains IDEs don't work (and they are not supported) under OpenJDK 6. They are really slow and have some visual problems when used with it.

It's quite possible too that your project doesn't work either in OpenJDK, I mean that this is not an IDE problem, but some problem in your own project.

PyCharm, 2.0 at least, and likely IntellJ, works nicely under OpenJDK 7, but it's still not supported (it doesn't support Oracle Java 7 either). Note that this means that it's not supported to run the IDE under this VMs, not that you program with those VMs as targets is not supported (it is).

So you have two options:

- Move to Oracle JDK 6 (you will need to install it from the Oracle web).
- Move to OpenJDK 7.

The best answer depends on your project. OpenJDK 7 will be the best move to assure future compatibility (Oracle Java 7 is based on it), Oracle 6 can be the best fit if most of your users are using it.

Comment: If you need help to install Oracle JDK, or configure your machine to use different java versions...http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7

Comment: Thanks I've downloaded OpenJDK 7 and strangely it's all working fine. I remember 2 or 3 years ago when I was using Ubuntu, I used to compile my projects in IntelliJ using OpenJDK 6. I don't get it why it doesn't work now. Maybe it's the difference between versions of IntelliJ now and back then that one supported it and now it doesn't.

Comment: ¿Why was this answer downvoted?. ¿Can it be improved?